# Comma in url shown as %2c%

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have  question:

My route is as follows:

```
_routes.MapRoute(
    "VideoWithQualitySystem",
    "videolar/{category},{subject},{sicknes},{tags},{gender},{hospital},{medicalCenter},{doctors}",
    new { controller = "Video", action = "VideoList" },
    new {
        category = new CategoryConstraint(),
        subject = new SubjectConstraint(),
        sicknes = new SicknessesConstraint(),
        tags = new TagsConstraint(),
        gender = new GenderConstraint(),
        hospital = new CompanyContraint(),
        medicalCenter = new MedicalCenterConstraint(),
        doctors = new DoctorConstraint() });
```

Can you see problem in this route? When I type "," in URL, my route is not working. And my comma shown as "%2c%

Comment: no we can't see your problem, please define it...

Comment: Can't you use `/` instead of `,`?

Comment: The "comma" is part/used on the url parameters. Use some other symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`,` is a reserved as per my understanding so I would suggest you not to use it.

[URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

2.2. Reserved Characters

Many URI include components consisting of or delimited by, certain
   special characters.  These characters are called "reserved", since
   their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
   purpose.  If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
   reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
   forming the URI.

```
  reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
                "$" | ","
```

The "reserved" syntax class above refers to those characters that are
   allowed within a URI, but which may not be allowed within a
   particular component of the generic URI syntax; they are used as
   delimiters of the components described in Section 3.

Also [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html#sec-2.2)

Comment: Okey my url is as follow:
www.example/videos/category1,category2,category3/sex/hospital/doctor

But in my url category1 and category2 and category3(may be 1 or too many) can be null/empty. Also sex or hospital or doctor also can be null. How can i do that.